# 3D graphics: WPF vs Direct3D

Tags: .net, 3d

Are WPF and Direct3D drawing speeds comparable on complex 3D scene? If not, why? Will some day converge?

What are other WPF limitations in terms of CG advanced effects for example?

Thanks.

Comment: WPF is a foundation framework , Direct3D is a 3D graphics API. Both serve different purposes. This comparison is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Caspar. If you look around many 3D WPF CG projects exist (like this one for example: http://quixo3d.codeplex.com/), this is why I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two technologies are not comparable. If you want to draw complex 3D scenes effectively you need Direct3D or OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks David, can you explain better why? I read that WPF rather than relying on the older GDI subsystem, utilizes DirectX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).